# expected argument in a class

Tags: python, pygame

hello I created a class enemy

```
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hauteur = 249
        self.largeur = 353
        self.enemyx = 250
        self.enemyy=250
        self.dead=0
    def montre(self,win):
        if self.dead==1:
            win.blit(enemydead, (self.enemyx,self.enemyy))
        else:
            win.blit(poulpe,(self.enemyx, self.enemyy))
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(self.enemyx,self.enemyy, self.largeur, self.hauteur),2)
```

but when I call it in my my loop that draw the images

```
def images():

    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(capa, (854, 449))
    character.walk(win)    
    Enemy.montre(win)
    character.shoot(win)
```

I just put 'win' but I then get an error saying that I am missing the 'win' argument. This is the second class that I made and in the first one (character) it is working fine.

Comment: when you write `win.blit(bg, (0, 0))` in your function, where is `win` declared?

Comment: When you do `Enemy.montre(win)`, `win` is actually passed in as self. This is because you are calling the method from the class. When you do `Enemy().montre(win)`, this is equivalent to `Enemy.montre(Entry(), win)` where `self=Enemy()` and `win=win`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct an [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of the `Enemy` class:

```py
my_enemy = Enemy()
```

Use the instance to invoke `montre`. Either

```py
my_enemy.montre(win)
```

or

```py
Enemy.montre(my_enemy, win)
```

Comment: Its like do you use String.toLowerCase() in which we reference the String class directly or "THIS IS IN CAPS".toLowerCase() in which we use an instance

Comment: @blackpearl `character` is an instance object, but not a class object.